# JS pre-select dropdown option with cookie creates invisible dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have this code that selects the dropdown option the ***second*** time the user visits the page, based on previously selected dropdown option by the user with the help of a cookie. My problem is that somehow when the cookie is NOT set (ie: user visits the page for the ***first*** time) the dropdown list options are not visible unless the dropdown is clicked on.

Please see the code below:

```js
var saveclass = null;

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
   var expires = "";
   if (days) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
       expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
   }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var storeSelect = document.getElementById('StoreSelect');
    var selectedStore = readCookie('store');

    storeSelect.value = selectedStore;
    saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
    document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + selectedStore;
});
```

```html
<div class="controls"><select id="StoreSelect" class="btn" style="width: 100%; color: #000 !important;" onchange="setCookie('store', this.value, 365);StoreSelectPrompt(this)" name="store" required=""><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="x">Select your option</option><option value="01">Store 1</option><option value="99">Store 2</option></select></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to know if readCookie function returns something:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var storeSelect = document.getElementById('StoreSelect');
    var selectedStore = readCookie('store');
    if(selectedStore != null) storeSelect.value = selectedStore;    
    else storeSelect.value = 0; //your first element of the list
    saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
    document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + selectedStore;
});
```

Comment: Goodness, that logic worked like magic. Thank you g4b0.88, you're awesome!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct answer and upvote! You're welcome! =)